# Google Cloud Print from Android GMail

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, gmail, cloud, printing

I have setup Google Cloud Print, and it works great.  I love being able to print to my home printer, from my phone no matter where I am.

However, the one thing I can't seem to print are GMail emails.  I'm using the GMail app (not website) on my Galaxy S3.

Everything else I can use [Cloud Print](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pauloslf.cloudprint) and then just Share to it, and it will print.  GMail doesn't work like that however.

Regular email is a pain as well, as I need to save the email, then I can share it.

So my question is, how do I print email through Google Cloud Print, from my S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised there was no official Google app. I am using [Cloud Print](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pauloslf.cloudprint) on my Galaxy S3.

Comment: The OP asks about printing from GMail using Cloud Print, just FYI, so your post doesn't answer the question.

Comment: oops, see what happens when i go off looking for a solution and wind up right back where the question started

Comment: @olore, no worries.  I've been using Cloud Print for a while, seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Looks like there is an official app now
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint